# Does identity exist for HCF/GCD of two numbers?

Tags: functions, relations

There's a question in my textbook:

Let * be the binary operation on N defined by a*b = HCF of a and b. Does there exist identity for this binary operation on N?

According to me the answer should be yes, since a*(any multiple of a)=a. However, the answer is given as no in the answers.

What is the answer?

Comment: What do you think the identity is? Can you give me an $e$ with $a*e=a$ for all $a\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

The identity must work for every element: you need some number $e$ such that
$$
e*a=a
$$
*for all $a$*.

In particular, $e$ should be a multiple of $a$, *for every $a$*.

Such a number does exist and is $0$, if you allow it in the natural numbers and also define $\gcd(0,0)=0$. Some people don't list $0$ among the natural numbers, some others don't define $\gcd(0,0)$. So the answer depends on the conventions your textbook uses. Personally I see no reason for avoiding $0$, but others don't agree.